Error while upgrading ubuntu from 23.10 to 24.04
Finaly, upgrade came to me but I have some problems with it. I tried to upgrade and 1st step was good, only with warning that third-party sources aren't enabled and I can do that after upgrade. I came through it and in the next step, I got this error message:
W:Aktualizaci z takového repositáře nelze provést zabezpečeně a je proto implicitně zakázána., W:Podrobnosti o vytváření a nastavení repositářů naleznete v manuálové stránce apt-secure(8)., E:Repositář „http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates Release“ neobsahuje soubor Release., W:Aktualizaci z takového repositáře nelze provést zabezpečeně a je proto implicitně zakázána., W:Podrobnosti o vytváření a nastavení repositářů naleznete v manuálové stránce apt-secure(8)., E:Repositář „http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security Release“ neobsahuje soubor Release.
In englishi, through Google Translator it's W:Updating from such a repository cannot be performed securely and is therefore implicitly disabled., W:See the apt-secure(8) man page for details on creating and setting up repositories., E:Repository "http://cz.archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu kinetic-updates Release" does not contain a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository cannot be done securely and is therefore disabled by default., W:See the apt-secure(8) man page for details on creating and setting up repositories., E :Repository "http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security Release" does not contain a Release file. Over this message I've got message that said I don't have internet connection but everything else works (web).

Try fresh installing.

Does this answer your question? What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?

E: means error and W: means warning, the sources are also represented in Software & Updates, you can go there and in Other Software either remove the mark or remove them completely.
